Does fluid amplify sound?
I was wondering if water amplifies sound like a speaker? It seems counterintuitive since there is no external energy used. I came to think about it since they advise pregnant people to not put headphones on the belly since the amniotic fluid can amplify the sound and make it reach dangerous levels. But can the volume ever be higher than the output volume? Is that a myth?

Off hand I don't see how the sound energy can increase. Perhaps the amniotic fluid somehow concentrates the sound energy into a smaller volume (increases the sound density)?

The total amount of sound energy cannot be increased just by passing it through water, so water does not amplify sound. However, it could focus sound waves.

Water does not amplify sound. Sound travels faster in water than in air, but this is not directly related to loudness. When sound travels from one medium to another (outside the pregnant woman's body to inside her body), some sound is transmitted and some sound is reflected. This means that the intensity, if anything, decreases on change of medium.
The sound from headphones may still be too loud for the fetus, but it is not amplified by the water in any way.
One root of this misconception could be the discrepancy in how decibel readings are reported in water vs in air. The loudness in decibels is 10 times the logarithm of the intensity of sound relative to a chosen reference intensity. This reference intensity for water corresponds to a pressure of 1 micropascal, whereas the reference intensity for air corresponds to a pressure of 20 micropascal. This effect itself produces a gap of 26 decibels in sound readings in water and air, but this doesn't correspond to any difference in absolute intensity.

You're correct that without external energy, sound waves aren't going to increase in total energy just from travelling through water. But there is a real physical effect, which sounds like it might be the thing those doctors were concerned about, though they perhaps used the wrong words to describe it. A calculation would be needed to determine if this is actually relevant for a given situation, of course.
When we think about what a speaker really is, it's a bit of solid material that we push on with a magnetic field. As it moves, it pushes on the air. If we shake it back and forth fast enough, it produces audible sound.
Air is kind of hard to push on in a satisfying way, you may have noticed. It's just too good at moving out of the path of your hand. In contrast, dragging your hand through water is much more satisfying. If we try and formalize what "satisfying" means here, one thing we might say is that you've transferred more energy into the water by pushing your hand through it than you would to air by pushing you hand through air at the same speed. Kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and a volume of water has much more $m$ than air, due to being denser (by about a factor of 1000 iirc). So to give a volume of air the same amount of energy, you'd have to get it moving much faster, and we can't move our hands that fast.
Physicists call this kind of issue "impedance matching". It's actually more commonly discussed in the context of electrical engineering, but there's a mechanical version too, which is what's relevant in this situation. According to Wikipedia, speakers tend to be only around 1% efficient, mainly due to this problem of impedance matching. So if I had a (waterproof) speaker, then it would quite possibly create sound of a higher energy when the diaphragm was pressed against the surface of water than when in the air, simply because the impedance of the water was higher, and thus better matched to the speaker.

Concerning pregnancy, I would highly recommend not to take any risk and listen to what the doctors say.
Concerning the question of amplification, I think a distinction has to be made between the physicists meaning of the word and the use in everyday life.
Meaning in physics
Amplification in the physicists meaning would require external energy (as this more or less the definition of amplifying a wave). Otherwise, you would be able to create at least a Perpetuum mobile of second kind.
Meaning in everyday life
In everyday life, “amplification” could also mean "absorbing it the wave less". E.g., in an acoustic guitar the signal is not amplified by the sound board. But without the sound board the energy of the string is turned into heat before reaching your ear.
Similarly, putting your ear directly to the ground if a Jackhammer is working nearby could be a bad idea.
